# Identify a block with same number in a dataset and create a blockID

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Using BigQuery SQL, how can I generate a BlockID based the first three columns?

For rows to be in the same block, the num_characters should be within the same ID and are consecutive in time.

| id | num_characters | date | BlockID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 90 | 1/31/20 | -1 |
| 1 | 34 | 2/1/20 | 1 |
| 1 | 34 | 3/31/20 | 1 |
| 2 | 34 | 1/31/20 | -1 |
| 3 | 34 | 1/21/20 | -1 |
| 3 | 45 | 1/31/20 | 2 |
| 3 | 45 | 3/31/20 | 2 |
| 3 | 45 | 4/3/20 | 2 |
| 3 | 56 | 5/31/20 | 3 |
| 3 | 56 | 6/3/20 | 3 |
| 3 | 99 | 7/31/20 | -1 |
| 3 | 56 | 10/31/20 | 4 |
| 3 | 56 | 12/31/20 | 4 |

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will produce the output:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 90 AS num_characters, DATE('2020-01-31') AS date, -1 AS BlockID UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 34, DATE('2020-02-01'), 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 34, DATE('2020-03-31'), 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 34, DATE('2020-01-31'), -1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 34, DATE('2020-01-21'), -1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 45, DATE('2020-01-31'), 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 45, DATE('2020-03-31'), 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 45, DATE('2020-04-03'), 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 56, DATE('2020-05-31'), 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 56, DATE('2020-06-03'), 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 99, DATE('2020-07-31'), -1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 56, DATE('2020-10-31'), 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 56, DATE('2020-12-31'), 4
), DataWithGroups AS
(
  SELECT id,num_characters, date, BlockID
         ,block_changed
        ,SUM(block_changed) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) as groupID
  FROM
  (
    SELECT *,
            CASE
              WHEN LAG(num_characters) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) = num_characters
              THEN 0
              ELSE 1
            END AS block_changed
      FROM data
  ) DS
), DataWithGroupsMembers AS
(
  SELECT *
      ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id, groupID) as group_members_count
  FROM DataWithGroups
)
SELECT id,num_characters, date, BlockID, -1
FROM DataWithGroupsMembers
WHERE group_members_count = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT id,num_characters, date, BlockID, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Id, GroupID)
FROM DataWithGroupsMembers
WHERE group_members_count > 1
order by id, date
```

[image]

First, I am grouping the rows in groups. In the next `CTE` I am defining which groups have only one element. In the final `SELECT`, for groups with one element we have `-1` as `BlockID` and for the rest we are using `ROW_NUMBER` to order them.